# What's the SO policy for swearing?

Tags: discussion, policy, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are expletives allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)

I've had a number of times when I've wanted to use explicit language in comments (in non-offensive, possibly humorous ways), but I've censored myself because I didn't feel it was worth the possibility of some overly politically correct user reporting me for being offensive just due to the phrasing I've chosen to use.

Personally, I have a policy of ***not being afraid of my own damn language***, but I know that this can lead to issues.

So I'm curious, does Stack Overflow have an "official" policy on swearing/explicit language/words-that-someone-somewhere-might-find-offensive?

Comment: Seems like a definite no to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233

Comment: As long as it is tastefully asterisked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/about-your-fing-website

Comment: Extensive discussion of one such issue in [Is the language “BrainF_ck” offensive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This seems pretty official to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233), being as Jeff Himself said it:

> ## No.
>
> Expletives are not acceptable behavior
> on meta or any other Stack Overflow
> site. If you can't effectively
> communicate what you need to say
> without resorting to lowest common
> denominator cursing, then keep it to
> yourself.
>
> If you use expletives, you will get a
> warning.
>
> If you continue to use expletives, you
> will be placed on timed suspension.

Comment: I've always felt that StackExchange is extremely professional, and that profanity is better suited to off-duty-hours conversation, so this makes perfect sense.

Comment: -1  for logic flaw of hasty generalization. A better answer, "Profanity is not allowed. It's inconsistent with the tone and purpose of SE sites." The flaw was to forget the significant amount of speech we hold dear that includes colorful language, and presuppose someone is "resorting to lowest common denominator cursing". If the Supreme Court doesn't assume the F-word is failed speech no need for us to.  *Please note I agree with the policy.*  Just not the auto-moral judgement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen_v._California

Comment: They say that intelligent people swear more often, shouldn't we try to invite intelligent people meaning they can use a language they are comfortable with :-) I understand not allowing to swear towards other people but things I think you should be allowed ;-)

Comment: "They" say? Sounds like a good question for the Skeptics stack exchange site... :-)