# Can we get an Announcement required-tag for (secondary) meta sites?

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, required-tags

For the secondary meta sites, we have tags like `discussion`, `feature-request`, etc. I really think we could use a tag like `announcement` as one of the allowed **required-tags**. I'm thinking of questions (!) like this: [Game Development Stack Exchange swag for top users](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/game-development-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users).

[Jeff Atwood](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/146/jeff-atwood) justified the post as a *discussion*. While I would never dream of criticizing the Great One :) , and I do agree that the post is *on-topic* - still, it really isn't a *discussion*. Seriously, what's to discuss? They're sending us free stuff :) Comment, or applaud, maybe. But it's not a discussion - it's an *announcement*. And it would be nice to have a tag to indicate that.

There have been other announcement-type posts, like when [Chaos engulfed the site](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/533/its-time-for-us-to-bring-the-chaos-to-game-development). Tagged as "discussion", belongs as "announcement." :)

**Update:** I've changed this request to cover only the *secondary* meta-sites, like meta.gamedev, etc. It has become obvious that the original meta.stackoverflow is unique. Its full discussion tag reads

> This tag indicates that the question is a discussion which may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and is often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.

Whereas the *secondary* meta sites discussion tag reads:

> The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.

Comment: Looks like there are tags [meta-tag:announcements] and [meta-tag:announcement] out there already but not used much. Both have only 4 posts in total.

Comment: @Siva, however they are do not have the same status as tags like `discussion`, which is one of the *required* tags. My first post wasn't clear about that, I immediately edited the second line to add **required-tags** as part of my request.

Comment: So you want this for regular users then? Anyone can just make announcements?

Comment: Siva, heh - we simultaneously deleted related comments. :) And @random - is that any worse than anyone making a *discussion*? It's just a slightly more clear indication of what the post is about, in my opinion.

Comment: Something tagged [announcement] you would think comes from an employee or maybe a moderator.

Comment: Making [announcement] moderator- or employee-only would be fine, it would still be more clear what the nature of the post was.

Comment: The "discussion" tag means "everything else". I'm sure that's the point Jeff was trying to make. The tag wiki excerpt makes this pretty clear already: `This tag indicates that the question is a discussion which may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and is often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.`

Comment: @Cody, yes, that is the text of the meta.stackoverflow *discussion* tag, but the meta.gamedev tag is different (as I put in a comment to random's answer), and is: "designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching *community consensus*."

Comment: My understanding is/was that the tag wikis from the main meta site (this one) were pushed out to all the per-site metas. That would mean you should have the same tag wiki excerpt. Has someone modified it to say something different? And if so, why?

Comment: I don't know who created the gamedev tag, but [read it for yourself](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion). It's entirely different. Maybe I should change my feature-request to be specific to gamedev (and other *secondary* meta-sites)?

Comment: I just checked a few other sites, and they *are* identical - to each other, and gamedev (but not meta.stackoverflow's discussion tag). So it sounds like that is what was intended - meta.SO is unique. Changing my post now. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) paired with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) captures the intent here just fine.

Even if you don't want to talk back or lay down some kind of feedback to the announcement, you're still open to that. And that's what marks it a discussion.

You could discuss size options for the shirts or possibilities of other types of swag that could replace the pens. The pie hole is ready for some filling. Whether or not anybody crams it pretty is up to them.

If you want, think of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) as marking a quasi-blog post. It's announcement that's open for comments and discussion of said notice. Go forth and feed back.

Using the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag also pops the question into the sidebar of the main section of the site, allowing for eyeballs and attention for any notices that may be of import to the rest of the user base.

Comment: The Gamedev `discussion` tag says it is "designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus." Sure, you can certainly discuss shirt-sizes, but does that really *make* it a discussion? And part of the reason I suggested a new tag, is that (currently) the top three posts on gamedev-meta *are* announcements (although tagged as discussion). They are purely *informational*, and not for the purpose of reaching a consensus. Not sure what consensus we'd reach anyway, other than "yes, we're in favor of free swag." :)

Comment: Also, regarding "being open to feedback [...] marks it as a discussion" - aren't *all* meta-tags "open to feedback"? [Feature-requests] can certainly generate a discussion, but that doesn't *make* them a [discussion].

Comment: I've commented on this answer in [my own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115021).

Answer (score 6):

I agree [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement) or similar should be one of the required tags.

Except on MSO, the four current required tags' wikis' excerpts are:

- **bug:** Indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed.
- **discussion:** The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.
- **feature-request:** You have an idea for a new feature, or for a change to the existing functionality.
- **support:** You need help with the use of one or more of the site's features.

Here are some examples where [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement) would be useful (and none of the four currently required tags is):

- [a post "[p]resented for your enjoyment-slash-amusement"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142) (if it were on a meta site other than MSO)
- [an announcement of a weekly topic](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/463)
- [a request for off-site activity](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/972)
- [an announcement of another Stack Exchange site's existence](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/679)
- [an SE2 migration explanation](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1)

(In response to [random's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101610): Note that not all of these were posted by moderators (or needed to have been), and that not all of these are suitable for [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) (being put in the main site's sidebar).)