# What does 'beta' state of a SE site actually imply?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

As stated from the questions title:

**What does 'beta' state of a SE site actually imply?**

Could someone elaborate, which restrictions or drawbacks we should expect from a *'beta'* SE site?
I could have well been missing something, that's already been answered, or is an easy to find policies concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beta sites aren't full sites.  They're sites in a "trial" period, to see if they have the potential to become successful sites, or if interest in them wanes and the community dies out.  From time to time, the site's community will be asked to [evaluate their site to ensure it is fulfilling its goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161033/which-questions-need-community-evaluaton).

However, terms of functionality, beta sites behave like full sites, though with [reduced reputation requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) for most of the tools, to make it easier for a brand new community to self-moderate.

The main difference between beta and full sites is the presentation.  Beta sites all use the same generic theme and don't have a prominent link in the site footer (they're buried under "more").

Comment: So what actually would make SE beta sites transit to _alpha_ (a _full site_)? The traffic, the acceptance and communities' activity?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ From what I know, a beta site will become a full one when the community and StackExchange as a whole considers that the critical mass of users and visitors will be stable for a significant time and that the community can function on its own. At that point, the site "graduates".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: In software, *alpha* is a state before *beta*; less complete still. We call sites that move out of beta *graduated*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters THX for pointing out, I meant mature state of course.

Comment: Whereas SE staff is of the opinion that the design is the only major thing that changes when a site graduates, it is actually also a much less technical question of being a first-class citizen vs an unfinished site under surveillance. This is especially a problem for beta sites which already have been anounced as being *elibigle* for graduation (and thus having been evaluated as fulfilling its goal) but not actually graduating before sitting a year in design-limbo without any apparent progress or notice thereof.

Comment: There is at least one other feature missing (migration paths). I seem to remember that there's more.

Answer (score 7):

Also, in addition to [Troyen's great answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239406/184589), another significant difference is that on Beta sites there are no moderator elections.

The moderators are instead hand-picked by the Community Managers from the pool of members that contribute with valuable content and demonstrate constant participation.

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't answer your question specifically, you can glean a lot about how sites are created and grow in Area 51. Some die on the vine too.

[StackExchange Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)