# How to contact Jeff Atwood?

Tags: support, status-norepro, contact, jeff-atwood, quora

I have a great idea for the company behind Stack Overflow and I would like to discuss it with Jeff Atwood.

How can I do that?

Comment: Post it here.  If it's really a good idea, he'll see it

Comment: There's always [profanity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/about-your-fing-website).

Comment: ...or sustained trolling: ["Jeff has my phone number, and he has called me before"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56163/why-am-i-suspended-from-area-51)

Comment: THAT sounds super cool awesome!  Can you share it with us?  I bet as soon as we hear it you'll be offered a position on the team!  Supercool!

Comment: Post a [pluralization bug report.](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: @Robert I just have to know, what's the pluralization bug thing about?

Comment: Why don't you go to his house? http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Berkeley,+CA,+United+States&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=46.677964,93.076172&vpsrc=0&hnear=Berkeley,+Alameda,+California&t=h&z=13

Comment: ^ Creeeeeepy... ;-)

Comment: I've already told him my idea of a one time credit card charge of $19.95 to bypass the quality filter.  I hope they cut me in on the deal.

Comment: @balpha -- how is this `norepro`?? this is not a bug or anything....

Comment: *Love* the [meta-tag:status-norepro] tag, that's classic!

Comment: I want to upvote this just for the tags.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: *"You have 1 items in your inbox."*

Comment: @Robert lol; with all the expert programmers around here I am surprised that mistake was made.

Comment: super creepy...

Answer (score 19):

See the link in the footer on each page: `team@stackoverflow.com`

Alternatively, post it here. Don't hold your breath for feedback though - although there will almost certainly be some from the community.

Comment: "although there will almost certainly be some from the community." - That's rather ominous =)

Comment: @jadarnel it's not meant that way :) Just saying that there will be feedback (praise or criticism or both) from the community before there will be anything official  - there may never be an official reaction unless they happen to really, really like the idea.

Comment: Also worth noting, Jeff is on vacation for six to eight weeks.

Comment: It's not a suggestion to paint the answer with bold, it's more like a business proposal. I tried to get in touch with one of the executives in stackoverflow via linkedin but for now without a success so I am trying everything I can. If someone can help me with my problem I appreciate it. Thanx.

Comment: @Rotem I'd say team@stackoverflow.com is your best bet. If you don't get a response from there (allowing a few weeks' time of course), it's probably safe to say they're not interested.

Comment: @Rotem Have you tried the [contact page](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact)?

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try team@stackoverflow.com & the contact page.

Comment: @Rotem How did it go? Were they interested?