# Why i can't vote a locked question?

Tags: support, voting, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Can someone explain to me why I cannot vote on [this "f***ing" question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/about-your-fing-website)?
Joking apart, why was this decision made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly, Questions (and answers) are locked because they fulfill any of these criteria:

- They were on topic at a given moment. They're considered off topic now, but still helpful.
- Entertainment aside, they do not add any value to the site. But they're just too memorable to delete.

There are other reasons for locks, but they do not apply here.

> Joking apart, why was this decision made?

Locked posts aren't considered good posts. You shouldn't be able to earn or lose reputation for something that would simply be deleted if it wasn't for these special circumstances.

See also: [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)