# New vote-button font hasn't been applied everywhere

Tags: bug, design, voting, fonts

A while ago, [the vote buttons were changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows) across the network. There were a bunch of design issues and bugs that came along with the change, and though a few of them have been fixed, some still remain.

One of the things that was changed was the font for the score:

> [image]

But the new font hasn't yet been applied everywhere. I [said in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows/389572#389572) that the new font hasn't been applied to [locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/about-your-fing-website):

> [image]

And today, I noticed that that the font also hasn't been changed on the preview shown when entering a duplicate:

[image]

**Could the font be updated to match?**

Comment: Resetting the font to the original would be a plausible solution as well.

Comment: @Redzsupportsthestrike ... and resetting the whole button design as well, maybe just as a sign of respect against the community.

Comment: @Philippos-prostrike- I completely agree.